# akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error when Spark Submit with Spray

Tags: apache-spark, spray

Wonder if anyone knew why I am getting following exception with a very basic rest service to print spark context version.  I am able to run it locally on IDE, but when place on server, the exception occurs

jar built with sbt 13.5 using sbt assembly
Spark version:  version 1.5.0-cdh5.5.0
scala version: 2.10.4 (tried 2.11.7 as well)
spray: 1.3.3

```
command: spark-submit  --class com.thor.rest.Boot Spark-Scala-assembly-1.0.jar --master local
```

**Error:**

```
[ERROR] [02/13/2016 20:31:17.882] [spark-services-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [ActorSystem(spark-services)] Uncaught error from thread [spark-services-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError: spray.can.HttpManager.akka$actor$ActorLogging$_setter_$log_$eq(Lakka/event/LoggingAdapter;)V
            at akka.actor.ActorLogging$class.$init$(Actor.scala:335)
            at spray.can.HttpManager.<init>(HttpManager.scala:29)
            at spray.can.HttpExt$$anonfun$1.apply(Http.scala:153)
            at spray.can.HttpExt$$anonfun$1.apply(Http.scala:153)
            at akka.actor.TypedCreatorFunctionConsumer.produce(Props.scala:401)
            at akka.actor.Props.newActor(Props.scala:339)
            at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:534)
            at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:560)
            at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:425)
            at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:447)
            at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:262)
            at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:218)
            at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
            at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
            at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
            at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
            at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```